# wget download only files from a specific folder

Tags: wget

wget - I'm looking for a command to transfer files from http://1.2.3.4:1234/ - only files and not subfolders or their contents

download...
URL/image3.jpg
URL/prog.exe
URL/doc.txt
URL/*.*

no download...
URL/dir1/image7.jpg
URL/dir2/setup.txt
URL/dir3/stuff.exe

wget.exe -nd -mnp -P D:\loca_download_map http://1.2.3.4:1234/

Tnx ;)

I think the question is quite understandable, but it is true that it is very specific and the bot does not understand it;)

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: `-r -l1` or `-r -l2` might be worth a shot. Note, you shouldn't use `-r -l0` (this is infinitely recursive).

Comment: -r -l1 is fine! thank you very much ;)